# I get 404 error when I click on "Get UI Kits" on Adobe XD

Tags: adobe, adobe-xd, custom-error-pages

When I click on "**Get UI Kits**" on **Adobe XD**, on the application's library page, the URL **https://www.adobe.com/products/xd/features/ui-kits.html#panel-3** comes and it is broken link.

I am trying to reach **Adobe XD** ready templates and libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The automatic coming URL link from the application is broken. Instead of the link from the application, you should use:

**https://www.adobe.com/in/products/xd/features/ui-kits.html**